# What is the option for presto to map multiple row to single file in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr, presto

I am using EMR service with presto enable. Created one schema under that created one table with external_location option pointing to s3 bucket.

When I try to insert data into the table through presto-cli every time it generated new file in s3. 
Is there any option to stored multiple row in single file in s3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto INSERT will always create new file(s), regardless of underlying storage. Moreover, S3 storage is write-once, there is no append.
To have one file, you need to write one `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE .. AS` query.

In a single `INSERT` query you can insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO t (a,b,c) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2'), ...;
```